# if statements and function arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, function, arguments

I have a function I have to fill out, and the only way I can see doing it is a mess. The function I have is:

```
public function($keys = array(), $pages = array()){}
```

Essentially the goal is:

- If keys are an array and each key is **not** set, do something.
- If Keys are not an array and are **not** set, do something.

The same concept goes for pages.

so that's four if statements, then we do:

*If key is array but pages is not, if pages is array but key is not. if both are arrays....*

What I have so far is:

```
public function sidebar($keys = array(), $pages = array()){
    $builder = AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::create('AisisCore_Template_Builder');

    if(is_array($keys)){
        foreach($keys as $key){
            if(!$builder->get_specific_option($key)){
                get_sidebar();
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(!$builder->get_specific_option($keys)){
            get_sidebar();
        }
    }

    if(is_array($pages)){
        foreach($pages as $page){
            if(!$page){
                get_sidebar();
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(!$pages){
            get_sidebar();
        }
    }

}
```

You can see its quickly becoming a mess. `get_specific_option` will check if that key exists. arrays are done like: `array('key', 'secondKey')` and so on. pages are done as such: `array(is_page(), is_category())` - each of those returns true or false, hence the boolean check. `get_sidebar()` will get the sidebar if, say for example, a key is not set, or a page does not equal true.

I am not sure how to create this function with out it being a disaster. Can some one help?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, it doesn't look that messy and it's quite short. What's missing from the function above...?

Comment: I am missing about 4 outher if statements which make it a mess, which is why I am looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove A LOT of complexity by always converting to an array (quick one-liner)

```
$keys = is_array($keys) ? $keys : ($keys ? array($keys) : array());
$pages = is_array($pages) ? $pages : ($pages ? array($pages) : array());
```

Your function now:

```
public function sidebar($keys = array(), $pages = array()){
    $builder = AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::create('AisisCore_Template_Builder');
    $keys = is_array($keys) ? $keys : ($keys ? array($keys) : array());
    $pages = is_array($pages) ? $pages : ($pages ? array($pages) : array());

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!$builder->get_specific_option($key)) {
            get_sidebar();
        }
    }

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if (!$page) {
            get_sidebar();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like a lot of potential sidebar inclusions. Just saying. But, you can pass `NULL` for either of the two parameters and it won't run the `foreach` contents at all.

Comment: This is not how we program. We need it on sperate lines for the diff files

Comment: @TheWebs Not sure I understand you. As it stands right now, this function would behave exactly the same way that yours does.

Comment: @TheWebs I'm sorry but you guys really need to improve your ability to read diffs. The whole point of diff is that it allows you to see partial line changes.

Comment: your function is a mess @Collin. Why? Because you have all your if statements (at least two of them) on the same line, the two bellow that are our coding standards. Lets follow them k? and No phillip, we need to see what changed on each line.

Comment: @TheWebs Right, because everyone here knows your coding standards? Exactly. Go figure it out yourself then. It would hardly take a trained monkey to convert the ternary statements to standard if statements, and still reduce the complexity that your example introduces. FYI: `diff` tells you what changed. On every line.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the value as null if the option is optional such as:

```
public function sidebar($keys = NULL, $pages = NULL){
  //Do something here
}
```

Might this will work for you;

```
<?php
    $search_array = array(
              'first' => 1, 
              'second' => 4);
    if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
         echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
    }
?>
```

Comment: this does not help me in any way shape or form.

Comment: @TheWebs added another option